# Odd behaviour of a Scala partially applied case class definition

Tags: scala

When I attempt to apply partial construction of a case class through a series of other classes, I get an unexpected (at least to me) result.

This is scala 2.11.12

```scala
object PartiallyAppliedWeirdness {
 
   case class Person(dob: String)(name: String)

  class Born(dob: String) {
    def namingFunction: String => Person =  Person(dob)
  }

  class Naming(bornPerson: Born,name: String) {
    def namingFunction: Person = bornPerson.namingFunction (name)
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val birth: Born = new Born("2010-01-01")
    val somPerson: Person = new Naming(birth, "Dave").namingFunction
    println(somPerson)
    println(somPerson.getClass)
  }
}
```

Result

```
Person(2010-01-01)
class PartiallyAppliedWeirdness$Person
```

How can this be! Can any one explain what is going on here?
Thanks

Comment: At line 10, `bornPerson.namingFunction` returns a function that takes takes a string and returns a person, i.e. `String => Person`. Line 10 also feeds the string in variable `name` to that function. So we get a `Person`. What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: okay, so ```(name: String)``` part of the case class definition doesn't form part of the case class signature, for pattern matching

Comment: Try `val x = Person("x")` and the error text will include, _"Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected."_ We can make a function type expected by adding type ascription: `val x: String => Person = Person("x")`

Comment: As for pattern matching, `(name: String)` isn't recognized only because the way that `def unapply(...)` is auto-generated. Write your own `unapply()` method and you can get both `dob` and `name` in a pattern match.